# Función almacenada ¿Cómo resolver el error "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo que realizar una función almacenada que cumpla las siguientes condiciones:

- Muestre el nombre de estudiante.
- La edad del estudiante mas joven.

Esto es lo estoy haciendo:

**Tabla:**

```
create table estudiante(  
    doc_est varchar(15) not null, 
    nom_est varchar(30) not null,  
    ape_est varchar(30) not null,    
    edad_est int not null,   
    primary key (doc_est));
```

**Función almacenada:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION menoredad()   
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC  

BEGIN
    DECLARE menor int;    
    SELECT nom_est, min(edad_est)
    INTO menor
    FROM estudiante;
    RETURN menor; 
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error:

> "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns"

Answer (score 2):

El error se traduce literalmente a "El SELECT usado tiene un número diferente de columnas". Comprobado la sentencia puedes ver que el `SELECT` devuelve dos columnas (`nom_est` y `min(edad_est)`) pero el `INTO` va sólo a una columna (`menor`).

Cambia tu sentencia para que o bien se seleccione una sola columna:

```
DECLARE menor INT;
SELECT min(edad_est)
INTO   menor
FROM   estudiante;
```

o bien vaya a dos variables en el `INTO` (en cuyo caso tendrías que definir la variable `nom` donde iría el primer valor):

```
DECLARE menor INT;
DECLARE nom VARCHAR(30);
SELECT nom_est, min(edad_est)
INTO   nom, menor
FROM   estudiante;
```

Aunque al final acabas devolviendo un único valor, por lo que me imagino que lo que quieres es la primera opción.

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido, soy muy novato, entendí muy bien su explicación y sus opciones, el resultado serian dos valores, por lo tanto me sirve mas la segunda opción, sin embargo tengo una duda, como debería ir el RETURN? por el momento se me ocurre que la sentencia quedaria algo asi : DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION menoredad()
RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN

DECLARE menor INT;
DECLARE nom VARCHAR(50);
set nom= nom_est;

SELECT
nom_est, min(edad_est)
INTO
nom,menor
FROM
estudiante;
RETURN nom,menor;
END
$$
DELIMITER ;

Comment: En MySQL puedes definir parámetros de entrada (`IN`) y de salida (`OUTPUT`). Quizás podrías definir dos parámetros de salida en procedimientos almacenados y de esa manera obtener los dos valores.

Answer (score 0):

He leído varias paginas y tal parece que no es posible usar una función para dar un resultado con dos valores,  seguramente el Tutor se equivoco, ya que según él se busca crear una función almacenada que arroje un resultado como este:

| Nombre| edad |

| Jonatan|  17 |

Siendo así y siguiendo las indicaciones de Alvaro Montoro la sentencia quedaría así:

DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION menoredad()

RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC

BEGIN

DECLARE menor INT;

SELECT
min(edad_est)
INTO
menor

FROM
estudiante;
RETURN menor;

END

$$

DELIMITER ;

select menoredad();

+-------------+

| menoredad() |

+-------------+

|          17 |

+-------------+

1 row in set (0.22 sec)

Gracias por su ayuda, quedo muy contento por su colaboración.